# Dynamic layout of content based on stored layout parameters

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to think of a way of creating data that allows dynamic layout of content based on the data itself.

As an example... imagine a photo app where you can overlay text onto the photo. But instead of putting the text anywhere you are given several options of different layouts.

One might have the text centered in the top.
Another might have the text left aligned on the bottom.
A third might have centered text on the top AND bottom.
etc...

How would you store these different options?

At the moment all I can think is to do something like storing the frame dimensions of the different "components". i.e. x, y, width, height. Or possibly AutoLayoutConstraint style dimensions. i.e. left, right, top, bottom or something.

Then when loading the components you can look at the dimensions stored against them and apply the layouts as required.

Is there a better way than this?

**EDIT**

Just thought of another way. I could create several "areas" like "top-center", "top-left", "middle-right", "bottom-left" etc... and "anchor the components using these area properties.

Comment: How about storing all possible frames in .plist? Easy to update, layout and code will be splitted. CGRectMake will help to make a rect for UIView component from 4 integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define a new type for the text position

```
typedef enum {
    TopCenter = 1,
    TopLeft,
    TopRight,
    MiddleCenter,
    MiddleLeft,
    MiddleRight,
    BottomCenter,
    BottomLeft,
    BottomRight,
} TextPosition;
```

You could use the a property to set the label's frame

```
@property (nonatomic) TextPosition textPosition;
```

In the setter you could do something like this

```
-(void)setTextPosition:(TextPosition)textPosition
{
    if (_textPosition != textPosition) {
        _textPosition = textPosition;
        switch (textPosition) {
            case TopCenter :
            {
                self.label.frame = topFrame;
                self.label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
            }
                break;
            case TopLeft :
            {
                self.label.frame = topFrame;
                self.label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
            }
                break;
            ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I think I'm going to combine this idea with Auto Layout constraints.